# Leaflet: How to calculate distance from center point to the edges

Tags: geometry, leaflet, mapbox

I am using leaflet draw control get geometries of certain areas. These geometries are polygons, line-string, rectangles and circles and I am putting them in a database.I want to get the distance from center point to the edges of these geometries.

[image]

I am using https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore to parse the geometry in this way:

```
var layer = omnivore.wkt.parse(geometry);
var center = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
```

I don't know how to get distance from center to edges. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible for `L.Circle` and only for `L.Rectangle` if it's perfectly square.

To get the radius of `L.Circle` is actually very simple. It has a `getRadius` method which will return the radius in meters.

```
var radius = circle.getRadius();
```

`L.Circle` reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle

For `L.Rectangle` you can use the `getBounds` method which returns a `L.Bounds` object which has `getNorthWest` and `getNorthEast` methods which return `L.LatLng` objects for those points. You can use the `distanceTo` method of `L.LatLng` objects to calculate the distance between them in meters, then you'll need to divide that by two:

```
var bounds = rectangle.getBounds(),
    northWest = bounds.getNorthWest(),
    northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(),
    distance = northWest.distanceTo(northEast),
    distanceFromCenter = distance / 2;
```

`L.Rectangle` reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle

`L.Bounds` reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds

`L.LatLng` reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng

The problem here is that if you don't have perfect a square, the distance between northWest/northEast and the distance between northWest/southWest will be different. That said, you can understand that such a calculation for the pentagon shape in your example picture is impossible because the distance will vary because it depends on the points from which you measure it.

Comment: Thank you, you really saved my day. :)

Answer (score 2):

For polygons, polylines and rectangles you can iterate through layer points (using `layer.getLatLngs()`) and calculate distance to vertices using `L.LatLng.distanceTo()` method or calculate distance to edges by using `L.LineUtil.pointToSegmentDistance()`.

Circles are more tricky, because Leaflet draws circles in current map projection, not as circles on sphere/ellipsoid. So, geodesic distance from center to really drawn circle differs for different circle points. You can use `L.Circle.getRadius()` as approximation and distance to bound edges as minimum and maximum of the distance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two colliders and want to get minimum distance between them, you may want to use `Physics.Distance`.